# How do I use the short_paths_dijkstra function properly from igraph?

Tags: python, igraph, adjacency-matrix

This is what I have tried

```
def weighted_path(g, u, v):
   x= g.shortest_paths_dijkstra(source=u, target=v, weights=True)
   eff=1/x
   return eff
```

How do I use it properly? I have no idea as to how to use igraph properly and can't really find the documentation.

Comment: Not sure if this doc helps https://pythonhosted.org/python-igraph/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#get_shortest_paths

Comment: @Python progrmmer let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the nodal efficiency for all nodes, then you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
from igraph import *
np.seterr(divide='ignore')

# Example using a random graph with 20 nodes
g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(20,0.5)

# Assign weights on the edges. Here 1s everywhere
g.es["weight"] = np.ones(g.ecount())

def nodal_eff(g):

    weights = g.es["weight"][:]
    sp = (1.0 / np.array(g.shortest_paths_dijkstra(weights=weights)))
    np.fill_diagonal(sp,0)
    N=sp.shape[0]
    ne= (1.0/(N-1)) * np.apply_along_axis(sum,0,sp)

    return ne

eff = nodal_eff(g)
print(eff)
#[0.68421053 0.81578947 0.73684211 0.76315789 0.76315789 0.71052632
# 0.81578947 0.81578947 0.81578947 0.73684211 0.71052632 0.68421053
# 0.71052632 0.81578947 0.84210526 0.76315789 0.68421053 0.68421053
# 0.78947368 0.76315789]
```

Comment: Hey Serafeim, thanks for the answer. I am trying to calculate the global efficiency of my entire graph by utilising the shortest_path_dijkstra function.

Comment: My networkx code: def efficiency_weighted(G, u, v, weight):
    try:
        eff = 1 / nx.shortest_path_length(G, u, v, weight='weight')
    except NetworkXNoPath:
        eff = 0
    return eff
def global_efficiency_weighted(G):
    n = len(G)
    denom = n * (n - 1)
    if denom != 0:
        g_eff = sum(efficiency_weighted(G, u, v, weight='weight') for u, v in permutations(G, 2)) / denom 
    else:
        g_eff = 0
    return g_eff

Comment: hello. the global efficiency of the entire graph is just the average over all nodes. so in my answer use: `np.mean(eff)`

Comment: For this:- RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  sp = (1.0 / np.array(g.shortest_paths_dijkstra(weights=weights))); would I have to construct some sort of a try and except set up?

Comment: No. it's fine. this is coming from `sp = (1.0 / np.array(g.shortest_paths_dijkstra(weights=weights)))`. the diagonal elements are `inf` cause the shortest path of a node from itself is not defined. you can ignore it. print and see `sp.diagonal()`